# Binance C++ API && Curl

Tags: c++, api, c++14, codeblocks

So i'm trying to make a simple bot using the Binance API. Its currently only for me i want it to analyse the market and when some pattern is completeed it should send me a notification to a telegram channel.

My big problem is i cannot get the API working. I included all header and source files. Also added the openssl data that was not included in the Binance files.

My problem rn is in the last few lines of the binacpp.cpp i get the compile errors:

```
    C:\Users\llbri\Desktop\binacpp-master\src\binacpp.cpp|1803|undefined reference to `_imp__curl_global_init'|
    C:\Users\llbri\Desktop\binacpp-master\src\binacpp.cpp|1805|undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'|
    C:\Users\llbri\Desktop\binacpp-master\src\binacpp.cpp|1809|undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'|
    C:\Users\llbri\Desktop\binacpp-master\src\binacpp.cpp|1810|undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'|
    C:\Users\llbri\Desktop\binacpp-master\src\binacpp.cpp|1811|undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'|
    C:\Users\llbri\Desktop\binacpp-master\src\binacpp.cpp|1812|undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'|
    C:\Users\llbri\Desktop\binacpp-master\src\binacpp.cpp|1818|undefined reference to `_imp__curl_slist_append'|
    C:\Users\llbri\Desktop\binacpp-master\src\binacpp.cpp|1820|undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'|
    C:\Users\llbri\Desktop\binacpp-master\src\binacpp.cpp|1826|undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'|
    C:\Users\llbri\Desktop\binacpp-master\src\binacpp.cpp|1828|undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'|
    C:\Users\llbri\Desktop\binacpp-master\src\binacpp.cpp|1831|undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_perform'|
    C:\Users\llbri\Desktop\binacpp-master\src\binacpp.cpp|1838|undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup'|
    C:\Users\llbri\Desktop\binacpp-master\src\binacpp.cpp|1840|undefined reference to `_imp__curl_global_cleanup'|
    C:\Users\llbri\Desktop\binacpp-master\src\binacpp_utils.cpp|99|undefined reference to `EVP_sha256'|
    C:\Users\llbri\Desktop\binacpp-master\src\binacpp_utils.cpp|99|undefined reference to `HMAC'|
    obj\Debug\src\binacpp_utils.o||In function `Z6sha256B5cxx11PKc':|
    C:\Users\llbri\Desktop\binacpp-master\src\binacpp_utils.cpp|108|undefined reference to `SHA256_Init'|
    C:\Users\llbri\Desktop\binacpp-master\src\binacpp_utils.cpp|109|undefined reference to `SHA256_Update'|
    C:\Users\llbri\Desktop\binacpp-master\src\binacpp_utils.cpp|110|undefined reference to `SHA256_Final'|
    obj\Debug\src\binacpp_websocket.o||In function `ZN17BinaCPP_websocket8event_cbEP3lws20lws_callback_reasonsPvS3_j':|
    C:\Users\llbri\Desktop\binacpp-master\src\binacpp_websocket.cpp|32|undefined reference to `lws_callback_on_writable'|
    obj\Debug\src\binacpp_websocket.o||In function `ZN17BinaCPP_websocket4initEv':|
    C:\Users\llbri\Desktop\binacpp-master\src\binacpp_websocket.cpp|89|undefined reference to `lws_create_context'|
    obj\Debug\src\binacpp_websocket.o||In function `ZN17BinaCPP_websocket16connect_endpointEPFiRN4Json5ValueEEPKc':|
    C:\Users\llbri\Desktop\binacpp-master\src\binacpp_websocket.cpp|113|undefined reference to `lws_canonical_hostname'|
    C:\Users\llbri\Desktop\binacpp-master\src\binacpp_websocket.cpp|118|undefined reference to `lws_client_connect_via_info'|
    obj\Debug\src\binacpp_websocket.o||In function `ZN17BinaCPP_websocket16enter_event_loopEv':|
    C:\Users\llbri\Desktop\binacpp-master\src\binacpp_websocket.cpp|133|undefined reference to `lws_service'|
    C:\Users\llbri\Desktop\binacpp-master\src\binacpp_websocket.cpp|139|undefined reference to `lws_context_destroy'|
    ||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
    ||=== Build failed: 25 error(s), 179 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 14 second(s)) ===|
```

As u see i want to run the example file but i don't quite get why these errors occurr.

I am Using win64 and code::blocks IDE

I would apreciate any advice

sincerly AD

Comment: Take the [tour], read [MCVE]. We **definitely** need your code!

Comment: Those aren't compiler errors. Those are linker errors. If you got this far, your code compiles, but some required libraries have been left out of the build instructions. We need to see the build command line or makefile.

Comment: I am currently only using the example.cpp inculded by the binance api . Its more kind of a linking problem. So i can't really provide the code

Comment: Mind you, `179 warning(s)` scares the crap out of me. somewhere in that 179 warnings there are likely to be some significant logical problems you'll need to fix.

Comment: You didn't add the libraries you need to the project. Not much else we can say from here.

Comment: So everything i did was open the api files put everything in my IDE compile it and now i have this. The warning are all for json commands

Comment: It looks like there are multiple libraries that have to be linked with: libcurl, libwebsockets, and maybe OpenSSL (unless the sha256 functions are part of libcurl).

Comment: I now liked everything properly. The API comes with a include and a lib file. I added the libbinacpp.so file to linker . Now i get the error _../lib/libbinacpp/li/libbinacpp/lib/libbinacpp.so: file not recognized : File format not recognized_ Any idea?